ora2pg fails to connect and to convert a files from schema oracle
I tried to convert a lot of files with this command it worked well here is the command,
ora2pg -p -t PACKAGE -i  gpfdba_package_pkg_descriptif_ratio_cmn.sql -o gpfdba_package_pkg_descriptif_ratio_cmn.pg.sql -c ora2pg.package.conf -b ./pg_new --no_header -P 0 -J 0

now I need to covert the packages from an oracle schema, I did what was necessary: ​​I modified the .conf file and I put the right connection, now I just have to find the right command to generate all the packages on this diagram I used this command but it didn't work
ora2pg -p -t PACKAGE -a -o aab_test.sql  -c ora2pg.package.conf -b /home/testauto  -w sungard


and i got this error
WARNING: NO_LOB_LOCATOR is deprecated, use USE_LOB_LOCATOR instead see documentation about the logic change. WARNING: NO_BLOB_EXPORT is deprecated, use ENABLE_BLOB_EXPORT instead see documentation about the logic change. WARNING: Enforcing KEEP_PKEY_NAMES to 1 as USE_TABLESPACE is enabled. /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck 
.
Does anyone have an answer and thank you very much

The perl error messages is almost certainly caused by mixing two perl installations. The OS's system perl (/usr/bin/perl) is trying to load a library built under a different version or configuration of perl (one likely installed under /usr/local). You may need to look at the settings of environment variables like PATH, PERL5LIB etc.
